# Why is libstdc++ `std::sort` not excluding the pivot from its to sub-ranges?

Tags: c++, stl, quicksort, libstdc++

The implementation of libstdc++ `std::sort` is the following (taken from [here](https://github.com/gcc-mirror/gcc/blob/d9375e490072d1aae73a93949aa158fcd2a27018/libstdc%2B%2B-v3/include/bits/stl_algo.h#L1929))

```
template<typename _RandomAccessIterator, typename _Size, typename _Compare>
void
__introsort_loop(_RandomAccessIterator __first,
         _RandomAccessIterator __last,
         _Size __depth_limit, _Compare __comp)
{
  while (__last - __first > int(_S_threshold))
  {
    if (__depth_limit == 0)
    {
      std::__partial_sort(__first, __last, __last, __comp);
      return;
    }
    --__depth_limit;
    _RandomAccessIterator __cut = std::__unguarded_partition_pivot(__first, __last, __comp);
    std::__introsort_loop(__cut, __last, __depth_limit, __comp);
    __last = __cut;
  }
}
```

Let us simplify it a bit to make it clearer:

- remove the standard library mandatory underscores
- remove the introsort part (fallback to heapsort if too many levels, not our subject here)
- remove insertion sort optimization for small arrays
- replace the loop with a second recursive call

If I am not mistaken, we then have this:

```
template<typename RandomAccessIterator, typename Size, typename Compare>
void
quicksort_loop(RandomAccessIterator first,
         RandomAccessIterator last,
         Compare comp)
{
  if (last - first > 1)
  {
    auto cut = std::__unguarded_partition_pivot(first, last, comp);
    std::quicksort_loop(first, cut, comp);
    std::quicksort_loop(cut, last, comp);
  }
}
```

But `*cut` is supposed to hold the pivot, right? So why is it included into the second sub-range? I would have expected something like:

```
template<typename RandomAccessIterator, typename Size, typename Compare>
void
quicksort_loop(RandomAccessIterator first,
         RandomAccessIterator last,
         Compare comp)
{
  if (last - first > 1)
  {
    auto pivot = choose_pivot(first,last,comp); // e.g. median-of-three
    auto cut = std::partition(first, last, [&](auto&& x){ return x<pivot; });
    std::quicksort_loop(first, cut, comp);
    std::quicksort_loop(cut+1, last, comp); // Note the +1
  }
}
```

- How do we ensure that the algorithm terminates if there is no `+1`? If we repeatedly take a bad pivot then the first sub-range can be empty and the other would be the whole range.
- I guess the magic comes from `std::__unguarded_partition_pivot` that does a little different than `std::partition`... but I don't see how it works and why it would be better than just `std::partition` and this suggested `+1`. Any idea or references?

Side notes:

- The libstdc++ `std::sort` implementation comes directly from the original STL and it was already written this way back then (more or less).
- The Microsoft version does something very similar to what I am proposing, but it uses a three-way partition that returns two iterators with all elements equal to the pivot between them. See [here](https://github.com/microsoft/STL/blob/303df3dae6f5ed9fe4f1c35257f663af8355584a/stl/inc/algorithm#L7441).
- Regarding `libc++`, I really don't know what is going on, the code is 100 times more complicated :D

Comment: If nothing else, `__depth_limit` will ensure the algorithm terminates. Fall-back to heapsort is there precisely to guard against pathologically bad choice of pivots.

Comment: Introsort is more there to ensure nlogn worst case performance. Without the depth limit, quicksort is supposed to be n^2, not infinite. On the original STL implementation, introsort was not known, however, it terminated :D

Comment: Does `__unguarded_partition_pivot` actually include (operate on) the `last` element?

Comment: @500-InternalServerError Not on `last` that is not dereferencable, but on `last-1` (the true last element) yes. From what I understand, the trick in `__unguarded_partition_pivot` is that it puts the pivot in the first postion of the first sub-partition. Then, when iterating on this sub-partition, it will be strictly greater than all the elements, which mean that the new partition will not be a degenerated case. But then what is the advantage right? We take one more step on each degenerated case if I am not mistaken

Comment: [Not so fast](https://gcc.gnu.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=57916).

Comment: @n.1.8e9-where's-my-sharem thanks so much. Just to sum it up, there was a patch proposed to do exactly that pivot exclusion. It clould lead up to 3% performance. It is pending from 2013...